# Keep Spaces After replacing

Tags: c#

I am having string[] [value1 value2 value3] and I want to replace it by 10 20 30 and show it in message box. But after replacing it removes white spaces and displays as 102030

```
string[] values = headerData.Split(new string[] { "<#Tag(", ")>" }, // value1 value2 value3 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string text = "";
string val1 = "";

foreach (string val in values) 
{
   foreach(GlobalDataItem gdi in Globals.Tags.GlobalDataItems)
   {
      if (gdi.Name == val) 
      { 
         text+= gdi.Value; 
      } 
   }
}
MessageBox.Show(text); // 102030
}
```

Comment: You concatenate that strings without spaces (BTW you may want to use String.Join and GlobalDataItems.Any() to simplify your code).

Comment: text+= gdi.Value + " ";

Comment: White space between value1 value2 value3 can be more or less It can be value1         value2 value3 or value1 value2       value3 anything

Comment: give the Sample headerData and Globals.Tags.GlobalDataItems for checking...

Comment: <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)> this is my headerdtaa

Answer (score 1):

Set the split options to .None;

```
foreach(string val in values) {
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val)) {
text+= val;
}
   foreach(GlobalDataItem gdi in Globals.Tags.GlobalDataItems)
   {
      if (gdi.Name == val) 
      { 
         text+= gdi.Value; 
      } 
   }
}
```

This should rebuild your old string.
Another option would be to use a Regex and just replace the values.

Comment: White space between value1 value2 value3 can be more or less It can be value1 value2 value3 or value1 value2 value3 anything

Answer (score 1):

When you split spaces are supposed to be created in separate arrays because of the multiple separators provided. However, those are omitted because of the option `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` you have given in `Split`.

Replace this option with `StringSplitOptions.None`. Now, just concatenate the every alternate array that contains empty string to the previous element in the array.

I have provided updated code below. See if this could help,

```
string[] values = headerData.Split(new string[] { "<#Tag(", ")>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string text = "";
string val1 = "";

var updatedValues = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++ )
{
    if(values[i] != string.Empty)
    {
        updatedValues.Add(values[i] + values[i + 1]);
        i++;
    }
}

foreach (string val in updatedValues) 
{
   foreach(GlobalDataItem gdi in Globals.Tags.GlobalDataItems)
   {
      if (gdi.Name == val) 
      { 
         text+= gdi.Value; 
      } 
   }
}
MessageBox.Show(text); // 102030
}
```